# How to use hyphen while passing object property as an argument

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pass object property as an argument. The Object key contains hyphen.

**Object**

```
{
    "section-id": 1,
    ...
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let section of sections"
 (trackScrollLeave)="leave(section.section-id)"></div>
```

**Components**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.retrieveDataService.fetchData().subscribe(data=>{
            this.sections = data;
       });
  }

  leave(value) {
    console.log('Scroll left '+ value);
  }
}
```

It's outputting `NAN` in the console. If use camel-case `sectionId`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is reading it as section.section - id (undefined - undefined = NaN) try

```
<div *ngFor="let section of sections (trackScrollLeave)="leave(section['section-id'])"></div>
```

resource on bracket property accessors - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors